# Good or Bad?: copy and paste the source.list of apt-get from another Ubuntu machine?

Tags: 16.04, apt, repository, official-repositories

I have two Ubuntu servers:

- An Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS installed from a CD-R burned with https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server
- An Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS on a pine64 with a provided OS image from http://wiki.pine64.org/index.php/Main_Page#Curated_Pine_A64_.28A64.2B.29_OS_Images

What I'm struggling is about apt-get command. The apt-get command on the Ubuntu on the pine64 doesn't find a lot of packages which I can find on another Ubuntu. So, I'm considering to copy all of repositories on one and add them to another.

I'm a beginner in Linux, therefore I wonder whether this way is good or not, and why each OS contains different repository sources.

Is there any possibility that this way may cause problem?
Is this recommended or non-recommended way?

Comment: Not so sure but copying is ok but I think it will not go so well without the keys in the `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d` for some of the repos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No, you shouldn't.

In this case, you are comparing machines with two different architectures.  I suppose your Ubuntu server is an Intel- or AMD-based 64 bits computer, whereas your Pine64 runs on a different processor architecture. Packages from one architecture will simply not work on another, and may mess up your OS.

I suppose not all packages that are available on common Intel-based 32- or 64-bit systems are available on the single-board Pine64. That is because they need to be ported (i.e. recompiled and linked) to that platform. It won't work to download the Intel-based and see if they run on the Pine64.

To see if a package is actually available, it is enough to try and `sudo apt install` it. If it can't be found, or `apt` runs into dependency problems, then it isn't available through the official repositories. You may still be able to download a `.deb` from somewhere, and some packages are architecture-independent (they may be plain-text Python programs, for instance). However, that will be different from one package to another.

Comment: My server is on an Intel 64-bit processor and my pine64 is on an ARM 64-bit processor. So, they are different architectures. Is there any way to install some missing packages on pine64?

Comment: I added something about that in my answer.

Comment: What about to build from source codes?

Comment: Building packages from source codes is of course possible, but it would be the same as porting the package; if it was easy, it would have been done already. If you can get it to work, you would be doing the Pine64 community (assuming there is one) a favour by publishing your package.